# How to load a key into IBM KeyProtect using Terraform

Tags: terraform, ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm, key-protect

I would like to use the IBM Terraform provider to provision a KeyProtect instance containing a standard key.

Getting a KeyProtect instance is easy: Use a [service instance](https://ibm-cloud.github.io/tf-ibm-docs/v0.8.0/r/service_instance.html) of type `kms`.

Does Terraform offer a way of inserting a specified key in the KeyProtect instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but should work... ;-)

The IBM Terraform provider is only for the cloud resources, not for "application data". However, there is a [REST API Provider](https://github.com/Mastercard/terraform-provider-restapi) which allows to execute calls to REST APIs.

IBM Cloud Key Protect provides such an interface and allows to either [create or import a key](https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/key-protect#create-a-new-key). This [toolchain deploy script shows an automated way of provisioning Key Protect and creating a new root key](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage/blob/master/scripts/pipeline-DEPLOY.sh) (read the [security tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/cloud-e2e-security.html) here). You basically need to code something similar to obtain the necessary token and other metadata:

```
curl -s -X POST $KP_MANAGEMENT_URL \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $KP_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    --header "Bluemix-Instance: $KP_GUID" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/vnd.ibm.kms.key+json" -d @scripts/root-enckey.json
```

---

#### Update:

The Terraform provider has [ibm_kms_key](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/kms_key#import) and some other resources now. It allows to import existing keys into either Key Protect or Hyper Protect Crypto Services.